# Multiplos alarmes com AlarmManager

Tags: android

Como setar mais de um alarme com o `AlarmManager`?
Recentemente criei um tópico sobre *services*, e para não acoplar muito decidi criar outro:

Vejam o código que estou usando:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Intent tarefaIntent = new Intent(context, ExecutarTarefaProgramadaReceiver.class);
PendingIntent tarefaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1234, tarefaIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//Definir o alarme para acontecer todos os dias às 10 horas
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                 AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, tarefaPendingIntent);
```

Ele tem um alarme às 10h, e um intervalo a cada 1 dia, e se eu quiser 2 alarmes? ex: um de 10 e outro de 11, com o mesmo intervalo de 1 dia?

Comment: Consegui a solução nesse topico [LINK][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469705/how-to-set-multiple-alarms-using-android-alarm-manager

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar diferentes Transmissão id para as intenções pendentes. Algo parecido com isto:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(load.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent appIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```